# Using sequelize to store and retrieve JSON objects within a Model/Instance

Tags: json, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm looking to leverage sequelize on a big project, and was hoping I could use it to store a JSON Object as a property in a Model.

I feel like I'm struggling with this, but perhaps I'm missing something simple?

I'm defining a model (`Context`) as follows:

```
var contextProperties = {

  contextName: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { is: ["[a-z]",'i'], notEmpty: true } },

  _trackList: {type: Sequelize.TEXT},    
  trackList: {type: Sequelize.TEXT}

}

var contextGetSet = {

  getterMethods: {
    trackList: function(){
      return JSON.parse(this._trackList);
    }
  },

  setterMethods: {
    trackList: function(v){
      this._trackList = JSON.stringify(v);
    }
  }

};

var Context = sequelize.define('Context', contextProperties, contextGetSet);
```

Now when I create my `Context`, it seems to work before I save.

```
var contextMain;

Context.create({contextName: "Whatever"}).success(function (context){

  contextMain = context;

  contextMain.trackList = { atrackList: "1111", anotherTrackList: 2872 };
  console.log(constextMain.trackList);
  //logs { atrackList: "1111", anotherTrackList: 2872 } as expected


  contextMain.save().success(function (contextSaved){
    console.log(contextSaved.values);
    //all values are null except for the contextName
  });

});
```

So the JSON IS setting right, but the object returned by the `save().success()` method does not seem to have the proper values of what I set it to.

When I log the object returned by the `save().success()` method (ie. `contextSaved.values`) the object looks like this:

```
{ contextName: 'Whatever',
  _trackList: 'null',
  trackList: null,
  id: 6,
  createdAt: Fri Dec 06 2013 15:57:39 GMT-0500 (EST),
  updatedAt: Fri Dec 06 2013 15:57:39 GMT-0500 (EST)
}
```

Everything is null!!

Even more weird is that when I look at the save SQL query made to save `contextMain`, it seems to be saving right!

```
Executing: UPDATE "Contexts" SET "contextName"='Whatever', "_trackList"='{"atrackList":"1111","anotherTrackList":2872}', "trackList"=NULL,"id"=7, "createdAt"='2013-12-06 20:59:39.278 +00:00', "updatedAt"='2013
-12-06 20:59:39.294 +00:00' WHERE "id"=7 RETURNING *
```

Notice that: `"_trackList"='{"atrackList":"1111","anotherTrackList":2872}'`

Also when I look at the actual SQL row for it, **it does have the stringified JSON object in there**!

If I load the Context using sequelize though...

```
Context.findAll().success(function(contexts) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(contexts))
  // also displays null for _trackList and trackList
});
```

So very strange. Any help greatly greatly appreciated!!
Thanks so much! Sorry this post is so long!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was apparently a bug with the getters and setters for the objects and resolved recently:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/759

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the setterMethod that is running JSON.stringify is getting called? Maybe its trying to insert as an object not a string?

More broadly, have you considered MongoDb? There may be other reasons why it isn't appealing for you, but just from this glimpse into the project, it looks like it would have real advantages--chiefly not having to parse json in both directions... but beyond that you'd be able to do things like query with the values inside that object, which might prove useful later on.

Comment: Thanks Zeke, I've tested by logging, and the getters and setters are both being called when the initial setting of the property is done. And the setter is also called when I save the instance.

Comment: Turn on sequelize debugging and let me know what the actual insert query looks like? Also check the record in the real db?

Comment: This is likely related to this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/759

Also, I am currently using a NoSQL (CouchDB). I'm excluding a lot of the details of my actual model(s) for this post, but the complexity of the project and the features of sequelize/ORM definitely seem like it's worth exploring it as an option. This is certainly more exploratory anyway.

The original post has the UPDATE query (near the bottom of the post), if that's what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for my comment formatting :/ should have been separate comments there!

Comment: Weird. Mongoose is a great ORM for mongodb, if you haven't checked it out yet. What if you don't JSON.parse in the getter? Just return the string?